# Where does Thunderbird store 'right-click' filters?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

Context: Thunderbird 26 beta, Windows 7

One of the nice things about Thunderbird (and for me, one of the most intensely irritating) is the ability to create filters by right-clicking the sender's email address and selecting `Create Filter From...`

The irritation comes from this: where is the filter stored? It does not appear in the list of filters when selected from the menu via `Tools>Message Filters...`, so I have no idea whether it has actually been created or not. And I can't manage what I can't see.

This issue, by the way, has been with me for years and is not just with v26beta.

Comment: For multiple accounts you could try the **Filters for** in Message Filters. If the problem persists, please also check in a [new profile](https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/using-multiple-profiles).

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this question on the Mozilla [GetSatisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/how_are_right_click_filters_managed) site. The answers are interesting.